# How Did Ubuntu Save My Computer?

Tags: security

This may be the most bizarre question ever submitted to this forum. I realize that and I am sorry. But please believe me, the answer is very important to me.

A few years back, my computer (running Windows Vista) was attacked by a virus/scam. I was not able to use my computer. I could not enter safe mode. I could not use control/alt/delete. There was not one key I could press that did not bring up the virus/scam page. The computer was completely locked up.

I did get rid of the virus using Ubuntu. I can't remember how I did it. That is my question. How could I have done it? I could not gain access to the Internet with my locked up computer. I plugged in a thumb drive with a bootable copy of Ubuntu. Inside Ubuntu I was able to gain access to the Internet.

I don't know how to download to Ubuntu, so I didn't download any anti virus program (and if I had, how would I have applied it to Windows?)

All I can tell you is that once I gained access to the Internet, I was then able to do something to get rid of the Virus/scam. Can anyone think of what I might have done? Even if I had used some type of online anti virus software, how would I have applied it to Windows through Ubuntu? Any ideas at all will be greatly appreciated.

I have since been very grateful for Ubuntu as I'm sure it saved me a lot of money.

Comment: You need to understand the difference between software (including the whole OS) and hardware. Virus are software that can dramatically affect the OS they were designed to attack. Running Ubuntu in a live session means running an entirely different OS that has nothing to do and cannot be affected by any other OS already installed. However, if you didn't install Ubuntu (or reinstalled Windows) you solved nothing.

Comment: @EliahKagan OK. Feel free to correct and expand if you like.

Comment: Based on the information you've provided, I think [MichaelBay's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/942030/22949) is the most complete one that can be given. Windows malware would not generally affect Ubuntu, so you would have been unfettered from the malware *while running* in the live environment (or installed Ubuntu system). If the Windows system itself was actually fixed, then of course this depends on *what you did* in the Ubuntu system, but @MichaelBay's answer explains why you would have been able to do it from Ubuntu even though you couldn't from the Windows system that was broken.

Comment: " If the Windows system itself was actually fixed, then of course this depends on what you did in the Ubuntu system, but @MichaelBay's answer explains why you would have been able to do it from Ubuntu even though you couldn't from the Windows system that was broken".

Answer (score 11):

You need to understand the difference between software (including the whole OS) and hardware. The unfortunate event that you suffered is entirely in the software (Windows). It is not your "computer" that was attacked, just the installed OS (Windows).

Virus are software that can dramatically affect the OS they were designed to attack. Running Ubuntu in a live session means running an entirely different OS that has nothing to do with and cannot be affected by any other OS already installed.

However, if you didn't install Ubuntu (or reinstalled Windows) you solved nothing.

Comment: Well, OP might have run clamscan or something, but we can't really tell for sure.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto Yes, it's possible but unikely: *I don't know how to download to Ubuntu, so I didn't download any anti virus program*. The way I see it the OP just booted a live session and, having a "normal" OS with internet access made them think that "now the computer is fine". Of course, it isn't. It all steams, IMO, from an erroneous conflation of "computer" (hardware) and the OS, hence my comment. You seem to be attributing a level of knowledge that isn't apparent in question, all the opposite, actually.

Comment: Granted it is just speculation and this question cannot really be answered properly because we lack a lot of info. My previous comment was a very small remark on the fact that one does not necessarily have to reinstall an OS as the last line seems to suggest. :)